# Why are the "stats" only available for 10k users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation

This is **not** the same as [Why aren't moderation tools given to people with a history of good moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268077/why-arent-moderation-tools-given-to-people-with-a-history-of-good-moderation)

I'm only talking about certain parts of the [Stats Page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats) from the moderator tools. As described in the [Help Center about Moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:
>
> - Posts with extreme votes
> - Posts with the most comments/views/edits
> - ...
> - Recently closed/reopened questions
> - Recently migrated questions
> - ...
>
> If you poke around in /tools, you'll quickly notice that most of what's found there isn't directly actionable - it's *informational*!

I wonder why even the purely ***informational*** parts of this page are only available for high-rep-users.

**Some** of this information could be made available for everybody, without the risk of doing any harm.

Particularly the overview of the highest/lowest voted/viewed posts is tremendously useful for finding interesting "hot topics", even when they are in areas that one usually does not visit. Currently, there is the "Hot" tab on the main page, but it is not really structured, and the reasons why a particular question is considered as "Hot" is not always obvious. There is no "Cold" tab for the low-voted ones, either.

Certain categories, like the "Most edited" or "Recently protected", would probably *not* be interesting for new users, and could be omitted for them.

Is there any reason why some of this information is not available to a broader audience, and not placed more prominently on the main site?

The only reason that I could imagine would be an increased volatility: When a question with extreme votes is shown more prominently, chances are high that the votes quickly become even more extreme.

On the other hand, this information could serve as a practial overview of "How to ask" and "How not to ask", but maybe this would only be a side effect.

<sub>(Note: This is not a "feature request". I do *not* "request" to make this information available, but only wonder whether there is a reason to *not* make it available)</sub>

Comment: Well one reason would be to keep the incentive to reach 10K, I guess.

Comment: @user000001 There are *many* privileges activated at 10k. The "extreme votes/views" parts of the "Stats" page are only a tiny part of them. Compared to, for example, the ability to view deleted posts, the ability to view these stats requires not as much "rep-based justification": They are mainly a handy overview to find interesting posts. They only summarize *information* that could (with some effort) also be extracted manually by browsing the public parts of the site. I just don't understand why these stats are so "hidden" in a deeply-nested tab that is only available for 10k users...

Comment: The stats are basically the entire moderator tools. In fact, if you remove the stats privilege from 10k then all you're left with is 'new answers to old questions' which you could argue is a stat too in which case the only privileges you receive are 'inline tag editing', 'view deleted posts', and 'delete votes on questions closed for 2 days or more'. Which are pretty minor privileges to be honest.

Comment: @Rapptz I wouldn't call "view deleted posts" as a minor privilege, it's one of the read-only privileges you cannot get from the data dump or from the data explorer.

Comment: @Rapptz Delete votes are not minor.

Comment: @bjb568 Sure. But the ones you get at 10k are. You have to wait 2 days for you to be able to delete anything. The real delete vote privilege is at 20k when you can delete answers and questions right away.

Comment: @Rapptz Meh, that's an annoyance, but it's not that hard to find old questions to delete.

Comment: @bjb568 You don't go around looking for questions to delete. It shouldn't work that way. Also, your lone vote count doesn't count for much. The amount of delete votes needed varies by question and their upvotes, answer, etc. It's a complicated formula.

Comment: @Rapptz Why wouldn't you look for questions to delete?

Comment: @SztupY And unless you're actively keeping bookmarks for deleted posts, you won't be able to search for them. The ability to view deleted posts doesn't change search results or the data explorer for you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't nearly all the information you want to allow us low rep plebeians to see already available in the data explorer?

Comment: @wnnmaw There are reasons why not everybody is allowed to see deleted posts, for example. But the fact that this information is - as you said - already available is one of the reasons for the question. Why not offer it conveniently at a similar place as (or even as a replacement of) the "Hot" tab? (Again: I'm **NOT** requesting or suggesting to do this, just wondering why not. Even if there is no reason, except for the incentive and the effort that it might involve, that would be OK.