# Which question has the highest # of upvotes to views ratio?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, statistics, views

**Which question has the highest # of upvotes to views ratio?**

I suppose the answer might be a new question with 1 upvote and 2 views, so we should put some constraints on this query.

Perhaps the data scientists here can **come up with some useful constraints**. Maybe questions with over 20 views?

---

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345953/whats-the-average-votes-to-views-ratio-on-stack-overflow) popped up after writing the title. Replacing `avg` with `max` in the best answer's query yields `1` which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: not sure how useful this is: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/849581

Comment: It's a good thing SEDE is cached, otherwise the results would change as everyone clamors to see which questions make the list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're right, questions with low views will dominate this statistic. For questions with at least 100 views, the best ratio is 0.2 upvotes/view for [WiX localization garbled words under installer properties tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24360812/1288). For at least 1000 views, the ratio drops to 0.09 upvotes/view for [Display a MPI typemap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28075478/1288). (Naturally, expect those ratios to change as people find this question and click on those links.)

Here's the SQL I ran to find those questions:

```
select top 50 cast(count(v.Id) as float) / p.ViewCount as ratio, p.id as [Post Link]
    from Votes v, Posts p
    where v.VoteTypeId = 2
        and p.Id = v.PostId
        and p.posttypeid = 1
        and p.ViewCount > 1000
    group by p.ViewCount, p.id
    order by ratio desc
```

It was adapted from [the answer by Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345955/1288) that you linked to. You can run it with different values in the data explorer: [Questions with highest upvotes to views ratio](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/849583/questions-with-highest-upvotes-to-views-ratio)

Comment: Maybe have those stats per tag instead of per question (aka, which tag has the highest upvotes compared to views) could also be interesting.

Comment: Anyone who clicked the first linked question must do `if (viewCount % 5 == 0) { upvote(); }`, otherwise this answer won't be valid soon :-)...

Comment: @Cœur Yes, that would make sense. I noticed that the few posts that I clicked on were in relatively low-traffic tags, even for ViewCount > 1000. When I add in the clause `and p.Tags like '%python%'` the top votes/views ratio drops about in half.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Questions tagged with popular tags (about popular topics) would have low ratios since everyone is searching for them, and not everyone has an account. Running your query seems to confirm this. We see the top ratios for questions about relatively obscure topics.

Comment: I doubt the linked question will be a valid answer for very long, since this question is now in `HOT META POSTS`.