# Which users have a ton of badges, but have very little rep?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I came across a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103606/peter-penzov) today with 52 gold badges, but only 425 rep. I soon discovered that he was just giving away a lot of his rep via bounties, but it made me wonder:

**Which users have the highest badgesCount/rep ratio?**

On a related note:

**Which users have the highest badgesCount/rep ratio that have never spent rep on bounties?**

Comment: SEDE exists for the purpose of sharing queries.  Use that site if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Oh woops. I got some positive attention on some other queries that I posted ([this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368663/which-users-have-the-highest-rep-to-total-posts-ratio) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367577/which-question-has-the-highest-of-upvotes-to-views-ratio)), so I thought that this was acceptable.

Comment: Maybe some users who like badges but really don't care about rep?

Comment: People ask questions about SEDE queries all the time, and this could be something that the OP was curious about.  At *worst*, this is a dupe since I could've sworn I saw a question about this at one point.  At best, this is fine and shouldn't be overreacted to.

Comment: It is probably more useful to find the users that sponsored a lot of bounties, get-it-over-with style.  Covered by [this Q+A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/top-generous-users-users-that-spend-their-reputation-in-bounties).

Comment: This account basically **hid** a lot of reputation so he can claim that he has the most badges at that reputational level. In short, he is really at **7275** reputation, but he deflated is reputation level and sacrificed some of his privileges.

Comment: Re *"...just giving away a lot of his rep via bounties"*: Or a means of transferring reputations points between sock puppet accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Which users have the highest badgesCount/rep ratio?**

We have to be careful to exclude users with 1 rep, since those users almost certainly have been banned.

We end up with a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/864653/users-with-highest-badgescount-rep-ratio?MinScore=2) like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 UserId AS [User Link],
  (SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id=UserId) AS Reputation,
  COUNT(*) AS [Total Badges],
  cast(Count(*) as float)/(SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id=UserId) As Ratio
FROM Badges
WHERE (SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id=UserId) >= ##MinScore:int##
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY Ratio DESC
```

When the minimum rep threshold is 2, the top two users are:

```
User Link        | Reputation | Total Badges | Ratio
user2497684      | 2          | 15           | 7.5
Narendra Sharma  | 2          | 13           | 6.5
```

Raising the threshold to 200, we get these two users:

```
User Link        | Reputation | Total Badges | Ratio
ant2009          | 636        | 886          | 1.3930817610062893
Peter Penzov     | 603        | 560          | 0.9286898839137645
```

**Which users have the highest badgesCount/rep ratio that have never spent rep on bounties?**

Excluding users that have spent rep on a bounty, we get this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/864654/users-with-highest-badgescount-rep-ratio-who-didnt-spend-rep-on-bounties?MinScore=200):

```
SELECT TOP 10 UserId AS [User Link],
      (SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id=UserId) AS Reputation,
      COUNT(*) AS [Total Badges],
      cast(Count(*) as float)/(SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id=UserId) As Ratio
    FROM Badges
    WHERE ((SELECT Reputation FROM Users WHERE Id=UserId) >= ##MinScore:int##)
    AND
    ((SELECT SUM(BountyAmount) FROM Votes WHERE Votes.UserId = Badges.UserId) is null)
    GROUP BY UserId
    ORDER BY Ratio DESC
```

When the minimum rep threshold is 2, we get the same top two users. With a threshold of 200, the top two users are:

```
User Link        | Reputation | Total Badges | Ratio
Sonny Ordell     | 209        | 79           | 0.37799043062200954
Tadit Dash       | 315        | 111          | 0.3523809523809524
```

Comment: I thought it was @rene who answered this sooo fast ! .. but no  :p